# ffmpeg Unrecognized option '--enable-libopus'

Tags: ffmpeg, opus

I'm running ffmpeg from a windows 10 machine.

My goal is to trim silence from the beginning to the end of a track (this works just fine) and compress using opus.

I am new in the "audio elaboration" world so maybe I'm not understanding this properly...but the main issue here is that ffmpeg doesn't recognize --enable-libopus although it's clearly in the options (see attachment).

Can anyone help please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--enable-libopus` in the build configuration indicates that libopus is available.

To use it as an encoder, you have to use the codec option.

```
ffmpeg -i input -af silenceremove... -c:a libopus -b:a 96k out.opus
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this actually worked! Another mistake I was doing was leaving mp3 as a format...I saw on another [https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/25506/convert-audio-to-libopus-with-ffmpeg](stackoverflow thread) that they were using libopus leaving the output file format as the input but that didn't work for me :/